Are device V-I charcteristics, applicable only during steady state?
I guess device characteristics are valid only during steady state. (For eg: I dont see any reverse recovery in diode V-i charcteristics).
Following chatgpt answer throws some doubt -It says "while V-I characteristics are often discussed in the context of steady-state conditions, they can also be analyzed and understood under transient conditions." How can they be used for transient analysis?
https://chat.openai.com/share/796167b0-50cf-43aa-8b1f-6b8c33264bec

Dynamic_equilibrium - Hi, I know this isn't as well-publicised as it could be, but it's clear from this Meta discussion that site members here do not want questions asking about what ChatGPT says. See that link for the reasoning. Therefore this question is closed. If you have your own position and evidence to put forward, which does not involve people here having to argue against ChatGPT (or other AI-generated output), then we can reopen this.

I-V curves should be accurate for low frequency analysis. At higher frequencies, you’d need to model the parasitic capacitances, inductances too if the part is packaged and the edge rates are in the nanosecond range or lower.
